# How to tokenize a text using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text, tokenize

I am trying to use the following code to vectorize a sentence:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization

text_vectorization_layer =  TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000,
                                              ngrams=5,
                                              standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                                              output_mode='int',
                                              output_sequence_length = 15
                                              )

text_vectorization_layer(['BlackBerry Limited is a Canadian software'])
```

However, it complains with the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndims'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first compute the vocabulary of the `TextVectorization` layer using either the `adapt` method or by passing a vocabulary array to the `vocabulary` argument of the layer. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

text_vectorization_layer =  tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000,
                                              ngrams=5,
                                              standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                                              output_mode='int',
                                              output_sequence_length = 15
                                              )

text_vectorization_layer.adapt(['BlackBerry Limited is a Canadian software'])
print(text_vectorization_layer(['BlackBerry Limited is a Canadian software']))
```

```
tf.Tensor([[18  7 11 21 13  2 17  6 10 20 12 16  5  9 19]], shape=(1, 15), dtype=int64)
```

The strings are tokenized internally. Also, check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization#example_2).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any easy way to understand each of this numbers in the output such as `18  ,7 ,11 ,21 ,13` is the map to which `ngram` ?

Comment: Use get_vocabulary of the text layer and text_vectorization_layer._lookup_layer https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization